# C# DataGridView Programmatically select row

Tags: c#, datagridview

What I need to do is basically select the first cell under an event, but I can't seem to figure out why this behaves the way it does.

on `dataGridView1_RowEnter` I'm assigning cell values to label and textbox

```
task.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["TASK"].Value.ToString();
```

I have a combobox numbered 1-5 that filters the dvg `priority` column

under `filterPriority_SelectedIndexChanged` I have my code to filter my datasource and then select the first cell so that the textboxes are populated with `dataGridView1_RowEnter`

heres the code to select the first cell

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 1];
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
```

this works by selecting the second cell then selecting the first, but if I was to select the first cell ONLY, my textboxes doesn't get populated.

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
```

Comment: Selecting only the first cell doesn't work because it won't trigger `SelectedIndexChanged` as the first cell is already selected at that point.

Comment: if the first cell is indeed selected, how would i get it to call an event? `rowenter` and `cellclick` doesnt work in terms of populating textboxes when the datagridview is populated

Comment: you don't need that code (neither `RowEnter` event handler) at all. just bind your label and text box to the same data source.